# Alamofire Image : Placeholder image is not set for af_setImageWithURL

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am using `af_setImageWithURL` Alamofire API to fetch the table cell images and pass a default placeholder image:

```
let defaultImage = UIImage(named:"myImage")
cell.imageView.af_setImageWithURL(imageURL, placeholderImage:defaultImage, imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.1))
```

**Problem:** When my image does not exists at the downloading path, cell do not show the default image as well. When I scroll the table up & down (to purge and re-use the same cell) then it shows up.

**EDIT:**

Noticed this is happening after dequeuing the cell, I reset the image first and then call Alamofire. If I comment out below line, it works fine but then I am running into a risk of showing old product image if both image URL and default images are not available.

```
cell.imageView.image = nil
```

Anybody faced similar issue, please advise.

Comment: ensure once the image has available or not `defaultImage`

Comment: `defaultImage` is perfectly fine and is showing the image. As I said, default image shows up on scrolling table view up and down.

Comment: can  you show some additional code related to this

Comment: Like what? What code do you want to see? I thought everything else is out of context to the problem here.

Comment: cell for rowat indexpath code

Comment: Found the reason why it is happening but still looking for a better work around. Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you cancel your request and also `nil` out the image in `prepareForReuse`. Otherwise you can run into a few different problems. Here's the `ImageCell` class in the `iOS Example` in AFI.

```
class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    class var ReuseIdentifier: String { return "org.alamofire.identifier.\(type(of: self))" }
    let imageView: UIImageView

    // MARK: - Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        imageView = {
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)

            imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            imageView.contentMode = .center
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true

            return imageView
        }()

        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.frame = contentView.bounds
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Lifecycle Methods

    func configureCell(with URLString: String, placeholderImage: UIImage) {
        let size = imageView.frame.size

        imageView.af_setImage(
            withURL: URL(string: URLString)!,
            placeholderImage: placeholderImage,
            filter: AspectScaledToFillSizeWithRoundedCornersFilter(size: size, radius: 20.0),
            imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.2)
        )
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        imageView.af_cancelImageRequest()
        imageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        imageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: what if we need to use Disk Cache with  af_setImage and URLRequest ,

Answer (score 2):

For swift 5

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/png")!
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder")!

imageView.af.setImage(withURL: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, this works well if I do not set cell image view' image nil just before Alamofire call. So, I am now setting the cell image view' image to nil only when default image is nil.

```
cell.imageView.image = nil
```